# Help with finding a "default" IP on a device with static ip

Tags: networking, ethernet, ifconfig

So I had a device that I connect via ethernet.

It had a default interface file like this one:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
        hostname dummy
```

I changed dhcp to static and set up a new ip but I misspelled the name of address for 'adress', of course now I can't connect anymore.

Does some kind of "default IP" exists, so I can search the device again to connect to ?

Then new interface file is:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        adress 192.168.1.101
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        hostname dummy
```

Any another suggestion or tip would be highly appreciated.

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: There is no "default IP"? As there is no default street address.

Comment: @Pilot6 thank u, well I wanted to post on linux, if we need to move it, it's oké. Yes I don't know if exist something like that, but maybe someone know how to search for the device, I can rephrase the question if needed. Thanks again

Comment: There is noting to post. You can't reach the device with misconfigured network interface.

Comment: @Pilot6 that's good to know too. Thank u :D

Comment: Which OS are you using, and which release number?

Comment: How do you know you misspelled the word "address"? Is it possible that you just typed the wrong IP address in? If so, try running:
`arp` or
`ip neigh show`
from a computer on the same network and see if there is an IP address that almost matches the one you are looking for.

Comment: Well I just scrolled up the same terminal, and watch the "cat interfaces" I did to double check, but sadly I didn't see the error at that time. Thanks for those commands

Answer (score 3):

There is no default IPv4 address assigned to interfaces.  If you have messed up your network configuration with static configs, the device will not have an IP address on the network.  Unless you have physical access to the box or some type of backup console access to the system there is not going to be a way to remote access the system.

(Also, 'adress' is not 'address' - you have a typo in there)